# How does an Artificer's Retain Essence feature interact with evil or cursed magic?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, artificer

I can't find anything that even addresses an Artificer using his Retain Essence ability:

> **Retain Essence** (Su): At 5th level, an artificer gains the ability to salvage the XP from a magic item and use those points to create another magic item. The artificer must spend a day with the item, and he must also have the appropriate item creation feat for the item he is salvaging. After one day, the item is destroyed and the artificer adds the XP it took to create the item to his craft reserve. These points are lost if the artificer does not use them before gaining his next level.

… on evil/cursed items. I have my own thoughts on the answer but I can't find anything written to confirm/refute my thoughts.

I preferring something official, but since I haven't found anything that might not exist (yes, lack of a rule stating it acts differently would default to "it acts as described for everything else") so if not if there's anything unofficial/3rd party that covers this that would be helpful too.

1. If an Artificer uses his Retain Essence ability on an **evil** magic item, does that somehow impact the XP he recovers? i.e., is that XP "tainted" with evil so the next item he makes utilizing his XP Reserve is also now evil?
2. If an Artificer uses his Retain Essence ability on a **cursed** item, does that somehow impact the XP he recovers? i.e., is that XP "tainted" with that curse so the next item he makes utilizing his XP Reserve is also now cursed?
3. Etcetera, as applied to good/lawful/chaotic items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It doesn't normally interact any differently.**

However, the artificer must spend a day with the magic item, so it'd be fair to rule he might handle an aligned item that could give him temporary negative levels for that day, which might affect his ability to use Retain Essence on it.  Likewise, if he handles a cursed item he could be afflicted with the curse for that day - or longer, if the item's curse can persist after the destruction of the item, or even prevent its destruction.

Also note that an item might give a different amount of XP than expected if a cursed item is misidentified as a different item with a different XP cost.

Comment: This is pretty much what I figured; I was just hoping something existed somewhere that addressed it. Gonna leave open for a bit longer before accepting just incase someone finds something